# Scrape socket.io data from website using python

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, scrape

I am trying to scrape latest bid and ask prices from this website "http://btc-exchange.com/"
I can see that the prices are being provided by this socket.io

```
wss://pusher.mistertango.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=XXX
```

The sessionID is being generated from this call

```
https://pusher.mistertango.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1517079662330-10
```

This is the code which I am currently using

```
import requests
from websocket import create_connection
import json

SID_url = "https://pusher.mistertango.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling"
SID_req = requests.get(SID_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
SID = SID_req[SID_req.index("sid")+6:SID_req.index(",")-1]
print(SID_req)
print(SID)

ws = create_connection("wss://pusher.mistertango.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid="+SID)
ws.send('2probe')
print(ws.recv())
ws.send('5')
print(ws.recv())
ws.send('42["subscribe",{"chan":"market-e559906eda4362f58bcaab40a4bfb5b4"}]')
while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    print(result)
ws.close()
```

This is the output of the code

```
    ÿ0{"sid":"mURV8OnaNqax_AmvAAF2","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
mURV8OnaNqax_AmvAAF2
3probe
40
```

The messages which I have sent are based on the messages I saw in chrome-dev tool.
[Websocket msgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2u39.png)

My connection stops receiving any message after '40'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem eventually?

Answer (score 3):

There is code of what you want. Tested and works

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

def on_connect():
    print('connect')

def on_disconnect():
    print('disconnect')

def on_reconnect():
    print('reconnect')

def on_aaa_response(*args):
    print('on_aaa_response', args)

def on_bbb_response(*args):
    print('on_bbb_response', args)

with SocketIO('https://pusher.mistertango.com') as socketIO:
    socketIO.on('connect', on_connect)
    socketIO.on('disconnect', on_disconnect)
    socketIO.on('reconnect', on_reconnect)
    socketIO.on('market-orderbook', on_aaa_response)
    socketIO.emit('subscribe', {'chan': 'market-orderbook'}, on_bbb_response)
    socketIO.wait_for_callbacks(seconds=10)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20212428)

Comment: Changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use asyncio and websocket to solve your problem.
You can use the following command to install websocket

```
pip install websocket
```

After that use the following code snippet as an example to communicate with the web server:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def responseFunc(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send("Hello world!")

url = "wss://pusher.mistertango.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=XXX"

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    responseFunc(url))
```

Ref: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am still not receiving any response using this. I am able to establish connection but not receiving response.